# How to overcome on "Undefined variable" error in laravel?

Tags: laravel, undefined, crud

I am using laravel 5.4 with xampp server. I am working on basic crud operations to learn laravel. Getting "undefined variable error" on any crud operation perform by me. My code works fine. after click on submit my data goes into db. but then to i get this error. How to overcome this error?

home.blade.php:

```
 @foreach ($companies as $company)
    <a href="{{ url('dashboard') }}">{{ $company->com_name }}</a><br>
 @endforeach
```

HomeController.php:

```
public function index()
{
    $companies = DB::select('select * from company');
    return view('home',compact('companies', 'company'));
}
```

routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('view-company','HomeController@index');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

public function index()
    {

$companies = DB::table('company')->select('col1', 'col2')->get();
        return View::make('home')->with('companied', $companies);

    }
```

You are not getting any thing in the $companies object, you need to define the table and than get(). This way you will get the laravel collections. and do not use * , try to avoid it, select the columns which are needed.

I hope this may help.

Answer (score 1):

You do not define `$company` variable in the controller, so remove it:

```
return view('home', compact('companies'));
```

Comment: thanks but its not working for me. still having the same issue. When i click on submit button to store my input it will throw error of undefined error and then if i go back and refresh the same page it will retrive my data and display

Comment: @amitsutar please show whole view and the exact error message.

Comment: Does the company table have values ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this :

```
public function index()
    {
        $companies = DB::select('select * from company');
        return view('home',compact('companies'));

    }
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<a href="{{ url('dashboard') }}">{{ $company->com_name or '' }}</a>
```

Comment: thanks but its not working for me. still having the same issue.